# OPROFILE can't get performance data

Tags: c, performance, oprofile

I am using OPROFILE to collect some performance data.
but I got in troubule.

**Here is my shell:**

```
~ # rm -f /root/.oprofile/daemonrc
~ # opcontrol --setup --no-vmlinux
~ # opcontrol --init
~ # opcontrol --reset
~ # opcontrol --start
~ # opcontrol --status

Daemon running: pid 14909    
Separate options: none
vmlinux file: none    
Image filter: none    
Call-graph depth: 0

~ # opcontrol --shutdown

Stopping profiling.
Killing daemon.

~ # opreport

error: no sample files found: profile specification too strict?

~ # tree /var/lib/oprofile/

/var/lib/oprofile/
├── abi
├── complete_dump
├── jitdump
├── opd_pipe
└── samples
    ├── current
    │   └── stats
    │       ├── bt_lost_no_mapping
    │       ├── cpu0
    │       │   ├── backtrace_aborted
    │       │   ├── sample_invalid_eip
    │       │   ├── sample_lost_overflow
    │       │   └── sample_received
    │       ├── event_lost_overflow
    │       ├── multiplex_counter
    │       ├── sample_lost_no_mapping
    │       └── sample_lost_no_mm
    └── oprofiled.log


5 directories, 13 files

~ # dmesg |grep oprofile

oprofile: using NMI interrupt.


~ # uname -a

Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 14 04:00:16 GMT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~ # cat /proc/cpuinfo 

processor   : 0    
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel   
cpu family  : 6    
model       : 44    
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz   
stepping    : 2    
cpu MHz     : 2400.085   
cache size  : 12288 KB   
fpu     : yes    
fpu_exception   : yes    
cpuid level : 11    
wp      : yes   
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb dts    
bogomips    : 4800.17    
clflush size    : 64   
cache_alignment : 64   
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual   
power management:
```

Comment: What are you actually profiling though? Your script just starts and then immediately stops the profiler.

Comment: i start the oprofile then run my app (not included in my script)

Comment: is this RHEL6 (or a derived distribution such as CentOS) ?

Answer (score 1):

Some CPU types do not provide the needed `hardware support` to use the hardware performance counters. 
On these machines, OProfile falls back to using the `timer interrupt for profiling`, back to using the real-time clock interrupt to collect samples.

you can force use of the timer interrupt by using the timer=1 module parameter.If OProfile was built as a kernel module, then you must pass the 'timer=1' parameter with the modprobe command. Do this before executing 'opcontrol --init' or edit the opcontrol command's invocation of modprobe to pass the 'timer=1' parameter

`modprobe oprofile timer=1`

Then continue your profiling procedure

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on a RHEL6 based distribution. At some point, I started using [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) with which I was able to get profiler reports and annotated source code.