# Oprofile operf is not collecting any data

Tags: oprofile, operf

I am testing oprofile version 1.0.0 out on two almost identical machines. On one it works perfectly on the other it does not collect any data at all. Oprofile was downloaded as source and compiled and installed on each box - with same version of all libraries/compiler etc

As root I am running and exiting with recommended CTRL-c

```
operf --system-wide
```

Kernel on both boxes is

```
2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is a difference in CPU's - this is working operf box

```
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 15
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            5160  @ 3.00GHz
stepping        : 6
cpu MHz         : 2992.426
```

This is non working box

```
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.80GHz
stepping        : 10
cpu MHz         : 3790.625
```

Even if the 2nd CPU is not supporting hardware profiling (not sure what flags to look for) is there a way to make it work - This mentions [OPROFILE can't get performance data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444885/oprofile-cant-get-performance-data) using timer mode but opcontrol is gone in version 1.0

Working operf.log file results

```
Profiling started at Mon Oct  6 14:22:33 2014
Profiling stopped at Mon Oct  6 14:23:56 2014

-- OProfile/operf Statistics --
Nr. non-backtrace samples: 1264859
Nr. kernel samples: 628924
Nr. user space samples: 635935
Nr. samples lost due to sample address not in expected range for domain: 0
Nr. lost kernel samples: 0
Nr. samples lost due to sample file open failure: 0
Nr. samples lost due to no permanent mapping: 682
Nr. user context kernel samples lost due to no app info available: 0
Nr. user samples lost due to no app info available: 0
Nr. backtraces skipped due to no file mapping: 0
Nr. hypervisor samples dropped due to address out-of-range: 0
Nr. samples lost reported by perf_events kernel: 0
```

Non working operf.log file results

```
Profiling started at Tue Oct  7 11:44:38 2014
Profiling stopped at Tue Oct  7 11:45:34 2014

-- OProfile/operf Statistics --
Nr. non-backtrace samples: 0
Nr. kernel samples: 0
Nr. user space samples: 0
Nr. samples lost due to sample address not in expected range for domain: 0
Nr. lost kernel samples: 0
Nr. samples lost due to sample file open failure: 0
Nr. samples lost due to no permanent mapping: 0
Nr. user context kernel samples lost due to no app info available: 0
Nr. user samples lost due to no app info available: 0
Nr. backtraces skipped due to no file mapping: 0
Nr. hypervisor samples dropped due to address out-of-range: 0
Nr. samples lost reported by perf_events kernel: 0
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Fred never did, just ran it on a machine where it did collect data.